# How can we use JSTL tag format data

Tags: java, jstl, liferay

Using JSTL format, I want to format data 30.0$ to 30$. how can we use jstl to format this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way in your jsp:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
    <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>
                <c:set var="balance" value="30.0" />
                <fmt:parseNumber integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${balance}"/><c:out value="$"/>
            </p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<c:set var="balance" value="30.0" />
<fmt:parseNumber var="i" integerOnly="true" type="number" value="${balance}$" />
```

Comment: Its not working properly bro :(

Comment: Should i have to Import jstl-api.jar as well?

Comment: i did it! but still unable to acheive my task